# Animations/Transitions canceled by "onserverclick"

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, code-behind

**first the good news:**

sourcecode:
http://jsfiddle.net/VWBN4/680/

I'm using normal HTML buttons in this example instead of asp:buttons just for jsfiddle. Normally i have to use asp elements to read their values in the c# code behind.

As you can see, i got a button which is changing it's color and size after the click event. It is exactly what i want to have.

**Now the bad news:**

As you can see, i defined `onserverclick="testfunc"` for my button and i got some code behind:

```
protected void btnStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //some functions like getting parameters from input, saving inputs anywhere, ....
}
```

**And now the main problem:**

After the `onserverclick` event finished, the whole website will be refreshed, my animations/transitions are canceled and the button's css class is reset.

Im looking for a good method, to perform my `onserverclick` to do some background stuff without interfering my client, the clientside animations/transitions and other stuff.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have your tried using ajax update panel. Put your things you want to update in the update panel and leave the button out of it. Then trigger the update panel update using the button from outside. Check this detail on update panel triggering http://www.markerstudio.com/uncategorized/2008/03/ajaxnet-update-panel-different-ways-of-triggering-updates/ . Another way is using jquery ajax call on client click of the button to do work on serverside code.

Comment: Yes i've tried updatepanels already. But the button was always in my updatepanel. I want to have some kind of animation for the button as a feedback for the user.
So i added the scriptmanager, an updatepanel, a contenttemplate and two buttons IN the contenttemplate. Maybe im missing something else?!

Comment: I have added code as answer. Please check it out on a test aspx page as it is to give you idea how to use update panel for this.

Comment: thank you for the code example :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution i think is to use Ajax Update panel. Using it's attribute `updatemode="conditional"` and triggers to the button (put outside the update panel) in question you can achieve the animation along with calling your server side code and also not have all the page to refresh in the process. Below is a test code i ran that you can check out for your solution.

**HTML Code**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style>
    .button {
        margin: 20px;
        font-family: inherit;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #bebebe;
        border-width: 2px;
        cursor: auto;
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 17px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px 30px;
        height: inherit;
        width: 220px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #e9e9e9;
        color: #252525;
        border-radius: 0px;
        user-select: none;
        transition: 0.7s;
    }

    .active {
        background-color: #00b2e2;
        color: white;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #008fb6;
        border-width: 2px;
        transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <script>
            function toogleClass(ele, class1) {
                var classes = ele.className;
                var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + class1 + '\\b');
                var hasOne = classes.match(regex);
                if (hasOne) {
                    ele.className = classes.replace(class1, '');
                }
                else {
                    ele.className = classes + ' ' + class1;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <fieldset style="padding:100px;">
           <legend>This is update panel boundary</legend>
           <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
               <ContentTemplate>
                   <label id="lbl1" runat="server">This is default Text</label>
               </ContentTemplate>
               <Triggers>
                   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnStatus" />
               </Triggers>
           </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </fieldset>
        <asp:Button runat="server" type="button" ID="btnStatus" class="button" OnClientClick="JavaScript:toogleClass(this, 'active');" Text="Status" OnClick="btnStatus_Click"></asp:Button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
protected void btnStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl1.InnerText = "This is altered Text after postback in update panel";
    lbl1.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
}
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding.

Comment: Thank you. It's working. I'm trying to create my own website since ... 2 days now, so some "basics" are missing. Your example was exactly what i needed!